# oracle sql generating shiftcodes based on pattern

Tags: sql, oracle11g

*I have 3 user inputs

- startdate : 3/14/2022
- focusdate: 4/2/2022
- pattern: 5D,2R,5E,2R  ( The code consists of number consecutive days and shift code. for example 5D means 5 consecutive days of shift D. 2R is 2 days  restday and 5E is 5 consecutive days of shift E. This can be any combination ex. '1R, 5D, 1R'  or '5E,2R'). After the pattern it will repeat in the beginning

I need an oracle sql to output what will be the shift( D or  R or E ) on the date 4/2/2022. The pattern will start in 3/14/2022.  The output should be R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the pattern and then use arithmetic to find which part of the pattern corresponds to the number of days between your dates.

*(Note: you can do it all using simple string functions, which are much faster than regular expressions.)*

This will support multiple rows of input:

```sql
WITH your_input (startdate, focusdate, pattern) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2022-03-14', DATE '2022-04-02', '5D,2R,5E,2R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-03-14', DATE '2022-04-03', '5D,2R,5E,2R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-03-14', DATE '2022-04-04', '5D,2R,5E,2R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2022-03-14', DATE '2022-04-05', '5D,2R,5E,2R' FROM DUAL
),
bounds (startdate, focusdate, pattern, spos, epos) AS (
  -- Find the start and end positions for each term in your pattern.
  SELECT startdate,
         focusdate,
         pattern,
         1,
         INSTR(pattern, ',', 1)
  FROM   your_input
UNION ALL
  SELECT startdate,
         focusdate,
         pattern,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(pattern, ',', epos + 1)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY startdate, focusdate, pattern SET order_id,
split_pattern (startdate, focusdate, pattern, pattern_id, pattern_days, pattern_type) AS (
  -- Split the pattern into a number of days and the type character using
  -- the previously found bounds
  SELECT startdate,
         focusdate,
         pattern,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY startdate, focusdate, pattern ORDER BY spos),
         TO_NUMBER(
           CASE epos
           WHEN 0
           THEN SUBSTR(pattern, spos, LENGTH(pattern) - spos )
           ELSE SUBSTR(pattern, spos, epos - 1 - spos)
           END
         ),
         CASE epos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(pattern, -1, 1)
         ELSE SUBSTR(pattern, epos - 1, 1)
         END
  FROM   bounds
),
days (startdate, focusdate, pattern, min_days, max_days, type, total_days) AS (
  -- Find the total days across the pattern
  SELECT startdate,
         focusdate,
         pattern,
         SUM(pattern_days) OVER (
           PARTITION BY startdate, focusdate, pattern
           ORDER BY pattern_id
         ) - pattern_days,
         SUM(pattern_days) OVER (
           PARTITION BY startdate, focusdate, pattern
           ORDER BY pattern_id
         ) - 1,
         pattern_type,
         SUM(pattern_days) OVER (
           PARTITION BY startdate, focusdate, pattern
         )
  FROM   split_pattern
)
-- Match the part of the pattern containing the date.
SELECT startdate,
       focusdate,
       pattern,
       type
FROM   days
WHERE  MOD(focusdate - startdate, total_days) BETWEEN min_days AND max_days
```

Which outputs:

| STARTDATE | FOCUSDATE | PATTERN | TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-14 00:00:00 | 2022-04-02 00:00:00 | 5D,2R,5E,2R | R |
| 2022-03-14 00:00:00 | 2022-04-03 00:00:00 | 5D,2R,5E,2R | R |
| 2022-03-14 00:00:00 | 2022-04-04 00:00:00 | 5D,2R,5E,2R | E |
| 2022-03-14 00:00:00 | 2022-04-05 00:00:00 | 5D,2R,5E,2R | E |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0b2XbJe9)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option; read comments within code:

```
SQL> with
  2  period (rn) as
  3    -- dates involved; startdate and focusdate
  4    (select date '2022-04-02' - date '2022-03-14' + 1 from dual),
  5  pattern (pattern) as
  6    -- this is your pattern
  7    (select '5D,2R,5E,2R' from dual),
  8  pattern_sum (pattern_sum) as
  9    -- sum of days (5 + 2 + 5 + 2)
 10    (select sum(regexp_substr(regexp_substr(pattern, '[^,]+', 1, level), '\d+'))
 11     from pattern
 12     connect by level <= regexp_count(pattern, ',') + 1
 13    ),
 14  new_pattern (pattern) as
 15    -- create new pattern (if period exceeds sum of days)
 16    (select listagg(pattern, ',') within group (order by null)
 17     from pattern
 18     connect by level <= ceil((select rn from period) / (select pattern_sum from pattern_sum))
 19    ),
 20  new_pattern_split (code) as
 21    -- split pattern into rows
 22    (select regexp_substr(pattern, '[^,]+', 1, level)
 23     from new_pattern
 24     connect by level <= regexp_count(pattern, ',') + 1
 25    ),
 26  shifts (shift, rn) as
 27    -- shifts
 28    (select substr(code, -1), rownum
 29     from new_pattern_split
 30       cross join table(cast(multiset(select level
 31                                      from dual
 32                                      connect by level <= regexp_substr(code, '\d+')
 33                                     ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 34    )
 35  -- finally, select shift which is valid on FOCUSDATE
 36  select s.shift
 37  from shifts s join period p on p.rn = s.rn;
```

Result:

```
SHIFT
-----
R

SQL>
```

---

For different period:

```
SQL> with
  2  period (rn) as
  3    -- dates involved; startdate and focusdate
  4    (select date '2022-03-18' - date '2022-03-14' + 1 from dual),
 <snip>
 35  -- finally, select shift which is valid on FOCUSDATE
 36  select s.shift
 37  from shifts s join period p on p.rn = s.rn;

SHIFT
-----
D
```

or

```
SQL> with
  2  period (rn) as
  3    -- dates involved; startdate and focusdate
  4    (select date '2022-03-23' - date '2022-03-14' + 1 from dual),
 <snip>
 35  -- finally, select shift which is valid on FOCUSDATE
 36  select s.shift
 37  from shifts s join period p on p.rn = s.rn;

SHIFT
-----
E
```